# Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующий код?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var catalog = "", pagen_1 = 1;
$.ajax({
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://vm1.culture.ru/abramtsevo/catalog/ajax.php",
    data: {
        PAGEN_1: pagen_1,
        EAR_SEARCH_LEFT: "-99",
        YEAR_SEARCH_RIGHT: "1999",
        TEGS: "Живопись"
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(catalog) {
        catalog += catalog;
        for (; ; pagen_1 <=10) {
            url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://vm1.culture.ru/abramtsevo/catalog/ajax.php",
            data: {
                PAGEN_1: pagen_1++,
                EAR_SEARCH_LEFT: "-99",
                YEAR_SEARCH_RIGHT: "1999",
                TEGS: "Живопись"
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(catalog) {
                catalog += catalog;
            },
        }
        $("#catalog").html(catalog);
    },
});
</script>
<div id="catalog"></div>
```

Ошибка в цикле:

> data: { - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

В чем дело? И как можно было бы лучше написать этот код?

Comment: здесь пропущен вызов `$.ajax` и вместо него сразу идет объект параметр.

Comment: Ох, и правда! Спасибо. А можно как-то оптимизировать этот код?

Comment: можно например не слать кучу запросов до того как получишь 10 ответов

Comment: Хм, это примерно как?

Comment: вместо бесконечного цикла сделать цикл по итерациям. Вот этот `for (; ; pagen_1 <=10)` цикл никогда не закончится, потому что условие не в той секции написано

Comment: Grundy, а можете ответить в рамках данного вопроса, почему мне в catalog 2 раза заносится одно и то же значение data (которое получается по pagen_1 = 1) вместо корректных разных значений с размым pagen_1?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46281/discussion-between-grundy-and-timur-musharapov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас пропущен вызов функции

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var catalog = "", pagen_1 = 1;
$.ajax({
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://vm1.culture.ru/abramtsevo/catalog/ajax.php",
    data: {
        PAGEN_1: pagen_1,
        EAR_SEARCH_LEFT: "-99",
        YEAR_SEARCH_RIGHT: "1999",
        TEGS: "Живопись"
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(catalog) {
        catalog += catalog;
        for (; ; pagen_1 <=10) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://vm1.culture.ru/abramtsevo/catalog/ajax.php",
            data: {
                PAGEN_1: pagen_1++,
                EAR_SEARCH_LEFT: "-99",
                YEAR_SEARCH_RIGHT: "1999",
                TEGS: "Живопись"
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(catalog) {
                catalog += catalog;
            },
            });
        }
        $("#catalog").html(catalog);
    },
});
</script>
<div id="catalog"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
...
for (; ; pagen_1 <=10) {
  $.ajax({ //       < - вот тут у вас проблема
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://vm1.culture.ru/abramtsevo/catalog/ajax.php",
    data: {
    ...
```